# Click events not working for marker attached to the line end

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have the below code. It consists of a line with a marker attached to its end. I wrote an on click event for line and marker. But when I click the marker element the click event is not working and also the CSS properties like cursor types also not setting up. How to write click events for marker element and apply css properties?

```js
$("#line12").on("click",function() {
  alert("Hai You clicked the line")
})
$("#arrow").on("click",function() {
  alert("Hai You clicked the line")
})
```

```css
#line12
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
#arrow
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600px" height="200px">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refx="0" refy="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#000" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="250" y2="150" stroke="#000" id="line12" stroke-width="5" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#RenderingMarkers).

> Markers cannot be interacted with. Events such as click or mouseover, for example, are not dispatched to a ‘marker’ or its children when the mouse is clicked or moved over a rendered marker.

It explains everything.

Comment: Is there any alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Marker element is not clickable, but you can place a i.e `<circle>` with `fill="transparent"` at the end of your path and attach your event to it. If you set radius `r` of this circle to `[stroke-width]*[markerWidth]`, it will surely cover the marker.

See an example: https://jsfiddle.net/91yuz4ng/

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Answer (score -1):

just try to not use defs and marker and move the arrow in my code to the end of line.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
    #line12
    {
      cursor:pointer;
    }
    #arrow
    {
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#line12").click(function (event){
            alert("Hai You clicked the line")
        })
        $("#arrow").click(function(event){
            alert("Hai You clicked the path")
        });
    });
    </script>
    <svg width="600px" height="200px">
        <path id="arrow" d="M100,100 L100,160 L190,130 z" fill="#000"/>
        <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="250" y2="150" stroke="#000" id="line12"        stroke-width="5" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
    </svg>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It is not working. The marker is not attached to the end of the line.

Comment: don't try to move the marker. just move the positions before creating and use border width of div to create arrow